# Export InDesign to Epub removed "^j' character

Tags: adobe-indesign, epub

I'm exporting a book to epub. In Persian, there is a special character that is used to make a small space without creating two separate words.

Adobe InDesign knows this character as "^j", But when I export the book to epub all of these characters were removed.

Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 2):

`^j` is the *non-joiner* character. It's equivalent in html is `&zwjn;`.

I can see that this character isn't included when exporting an epub from InDesign.

A workaround could be:

- In InDesign use *Find/Change* to change `^j` to some letter combination not used elsewhere in the document. For example `XX`.
- Export an *epub* file.
- Change the extension of the exported file from `epub` to `zip`.
- Unzip the *zip* file to a folder.
- Open the *xhtml* file located in the `OEBPS` folder in a text editor.
- Change all occurences of `XX` (or whatever you chose) to `&zwjn;`.
- Save the *xhtml* file.
- Create a *zip* file with the contents of the folder.
- Change the extension of the zip file from `zip` to `epub`.

Now the non-joiner character should be present in your epub.

**I don't know if this works as intended with Persian text in an epub reader!**

Comment: I actually ended up using this method, but I'm still looking for a better answer. why on earth they remove a character while exporting :|

Comment: Do the non-joiner characters work as intended in the epub?

Comment: yes, actually Persian keyboard has a combination to enter that character (shift+space). I didn't check that with html entities.

Comment: @AliKazemkhanloo - perhaps you found a bug. Probably best to report it to Adobe.